# Firebase datasnapshot.getValue(class) returns null even if getChildren returns values

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I've used firebase database and stored data as shown below.

But in the OnDataChange method, the snapshot.getValue() is returning null values to my class object as shown in the debug snapshot given below:

[image]

The code is as given below:

**Pani.java**

```
public class Pani {
    private String pid, pname, ptype, pfunc;
    private Pani()
    {

    }

    public Pani(String pid, String pname, String ptype, String pfunc) {
        this.pid = pid;
        this.pname = pname;
        this.ptype = ptype;
        this.pfunc = pfunc;
    }

    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    public String getPtype() {
        return ptype;
    }

    public void setPtype(String ptype) {
        this.ptype = ptype;
    }

    public String getPfunc() {
        return pfunc;
    }

    public void setPfunc(String pfunc) {
        this.pfunc = pfunc;
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Pani> listData;

    public MyAdapter(List<Pani> listData){
        this.listData = listData;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_layout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.pani_name.setText(listData.get(position).getPname());
        holder.pani_function.setText(listData.get(position).getPfunc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

     TextView pani_name,pani_function;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            pani_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pani_name);
            pani_function=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pani_function);

        }
    }
}
```

**homeactivity.java**

```
public class homeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Pani> listData;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.pani_search_list);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        listData = new ArrayList<>();

        final DatabaseReference nm = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Pani");
        nm.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot npsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Pani l = npsnapshot.getValue(Pani.class);
                        listData.add(l);
                    }
                    adapter = new MyAdapter(listData);
                    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also add the code as text and not as a image.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for your hint!! I imported the json file and found some unwanted "\" which may cause this issue. But I don't know why?. Actually, I created this database by manually entering values into each key.

Comment: If you are adding this line `Log.d("TAG", l.getPname());` right after `Pani l = npsnapshot.getValue(Pani.class);`, is something printed out in the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution when @Alex Mamo asked me to post the json file for the database. In the JSON file I've found some unwanted "\" which may cause this issue. But I don't know why?. Actually, I created this database by manually entering values into each key.

Following was the existing JSON content:

```
{  "Pani" : {
"\"Budget\"" : {
  "\"pfunc\"" : "hardware",
  "\"pid\"" : "1",
  "\"pname\"" : "Budget",
  "\"ptype\"" : "shop"
},
"Basheer" : {
  "\"pfunc\"" : "Plumbing",
  "\"pid\"" : "0",
  "\"pname\"" : "Basheer",
  "\"ptype\"" : "Person"
}
```

}
 }

I corrected into following format, and it worked!!!

```
  {  "Pani" : {
"Budget" : {
  "pfunc" : "hardware",
  "pid" : "1",
  "pname" : "Budget",
  "ptype" : "shop"
},
"Basheer" : {
  "pfunc" : "Plumbing",
  "pid" : "0",
  "pname" : "Basheer",
  "ptype" : "Person"
}
```

}
 }